# Uniform.js style alternative to SexyCombo form select

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently we use SexyCombo to style our drop downs. It has some problems that don't exist in uniform.js, but uniform is difficult to integrate into an existing site. Are there any alternatives to uniform I could use?

Specially our problems with SexyCombo are:

1. Events (either blur or click - not sure yet) triggering on the application of the styles (the js call to .sexycombo()) leading to validation triggering and ajax calls being issued
2. Tabbing does not change focus between fields

Our requirements are:

1. Styled background image
2. Styled drop down arrow image
3. Don't need styled options in the drop down
4. Works with jQuery 1.3.2 (if jquery is required)

Uniform.js meets these requirements. For example, see http://www.gourmetcat.co.nz/personalitytest?id=107. It has all the features we need, however it is a very heavy library that is difficult to integrate into an existing site. To be clear, we only need the drop down features, nothing else.

So are there any alternatives that have the features of uniform, that can be easily integrated?

Comment: I'm currently investigating the jQuery UI selectmenu library that is planned in an upcoming version http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138056/Selectmenu

Comment: Looks like jQuery UI selectmenu (https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui) isn't compatible with 1.3.2 (although the latest stable release of jQuery UI claims to be)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there is a successor to SexyCombo called UFD (Unobtrusive Fast-Filter Dropdown). Because it is a fork of SexyCombo, it is obviously very easy to use in my situation.

Luckily it addresses my exact issues - tabbing and extraneous event firing are fixed. They are clear to state what they have dropped to make this (and other improvements) possible (http://code.google.com/p/ufd/wiki/WhyTheFork), but luckily none affect my needs.

Go to http://code.google.com/p/ufd/ - it was the supplied bookmarklet that highlighted very quickly that this was going to work for me.